Copy Cosmos DB Prod over Cosmos DB Dev
Before executing an operation on the prod database that alters the records, it is a best practice to try this operation on dev DB made as a copy of Prod DB
There is a generic tool made by MSFT that does that:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-migrate-desktop-tool
However, it is slow (in comparison to a backup/restore of an Azure SQL).
We need a copy of Cosmos containers on a specific DB in the prod subscription to be restored to the same specs (but dev equivalent) Cosmos containers on the dev db. We want to do that on demand from time to time.
Is there an easy way to do so?

I find it very rare if ever that this is needed. I don't think you'll learn anything that you couldn't easily learn from some analysis and targeted testing without this. If I ever did need to do this I'd probably do a restore of the selected prod containers to a new account. do the testing and then delete the account

@MartinSmith there are other legitimate scenarios for this where you want to debug live data problems by copying the data into another subscription as the live subscription is usually restricted. I wouldn't call this very rare.

It's unclear in that case why the data would be fine to copy into a dev environment if the live environment is restricted, if the production data itself is not confidential and there is a BAU requirement for people to be able to see this for support purposes you could consider analytical store so people can run queries against it without consuming any RU and potentially impacting production queries.
In any event the only options currently are restore collection to a new account or copy all documents from source to target (slower and likely more expensive as incurs RU costs)

Accessing the live environment is restricted to the developers but you can always make an automated process that can copy the data to an accessible subscription on demand. We are not talking about confidentiality here.

This may be a good use case for container copy for Azure Cosmos DB.  You can find documentation at the link above as well as Create and manage container copy jobs in Azure Cosmos DB (Preview).

fyi - best to provide links as comments, as this isn't really answering a specific programming question - more of info-sharing.
